# mysql select a,b from y where a=1 and b does not equal blank

Tags: mysql

Just a basic question on syntax an/or if it can be done

How do I select all values from a column that meet certain conditions?

```
mysql> SELECT l_legs,a_calling_rtcp_mos_fs1 from ims_calls where l_legs=2;
+--------+------------------------+
| l_legs | a_calling_rtcp_mos_fs1 |
+--------+------------------------+
| 2      | 43                     |
| 2      | 43                     |
| 2      | 35                     |
| 2      |                        |
| 2      | 43                     |
| 2      | 43                     |
| 2      | 43                     |
| 2      | 10                     |
| 2      | 10                     |
| 2      | 43                     |
+--------+------------------------+
10 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

this is my attempt:

```
mysql> SELECT l_legs,a_calling_rtcp_mos_fs1 from ims_calls where l_legs=2 AND l_legs NOT = "";
ERROR 1064 (42000): You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '= ""' at line 1
```

what I want is to remove the blank space in the `a_calling_rtcp_mos_fs1` column from the output, so that I will get 9 rows.

Comment: Is that really a "blank" space, or is it a `NULL`?  You should clarify this in your question, especially if you want to answer it yourself.

Comment: I think it is a blank space. would a null not appear as a NULL? good point, tks.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT l_legs,a_calling_rtcp_mos_fs1 from ims_calls where l_legs=2 AND a_calling_rtcp_mos_fs1>0
    -> ;
+--------+------------------------+
| l_legs | a_calling_rtcp_mos_fs1 |
+--------+------------------------+
| 2      | 43                     |
| 2      | 43                     |
| 2      | 35                     |
| 2      | 43                     |
| 2      | 43                     |
| 2      | 43                     |
| 2      | 10                     |
| 2      | 10                     |
| 2      | 43                     |
+--------+------------------------+
9 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

Answer (score 0):

If it's blank space try this :

```
SELECT l_legs,a_calling_rtcp_mos_fs1 from ims_calls where l_legs=2 AND
a_calling_rtcp_mos_fs1 != ' ';
```

If it's `null` try this :

```
SELECT l_legs,a_calling_rtcp_mos_fs1 from ims_calls where l_legs=2 AND
a_calling_rtcp_mos_fs1 is not null;
```

Answer (score 0):

The `NOT` goes ***before*** the condition, not in the middle of it.

So instead of:

```
l_legs NOT = ""
```

Do:

```
NOT l_legs = ""
```

Final select:

```
SELECT l_legs,a_calling_rtcp_mos_fs1 from ims_calls where l_legs=2 AND NOT l_legs = "";
```